# Searched CASE Statement with Greater Than and Less Than Comparison

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a big calculation which will give numeric values and needs to be compared for greater than and less than

```
CASE big_expression 
  WHEN > 0 AND <5 THEN 'Less Than 5 Days'
  WHEN > 5 AND <20 THEN 'Between 5 and 20 Days'
  -
```

Can this be done or I need to use the expressions every time I make a comparison

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't be done. If `big_expression` is really big, you can compute it and give it a name in a subquery, and then have the `CASE` expression in an outer query.

Comment: A couple more notes... (1) case **statement** only exists in PL/SQL; what you have is a case **expression**. (2) Can `big_expression` be <= 0? If not, you don't need to compare > 0 in the first branch. (3) What if `big_expression` is exactly 5? (4) Normally you would write: `case when big_expression > 20 then 'More than 20 days' when big_expression >= 5 then 'Between 5 and 20 days' else 'Less than 5 days' end`. The comparisons (in the `WHEN` conditions) stop as soon as the first one that's true, so you will save coding if you write it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE for the same

```
        WITH data
         AS (SELECT 1 + 2 + 5 + 9 AS big_exp
             FROM   dual)
    SELECT CASE
             WHEN big_exp > 0
                  AND big_exp < 5 THEN 'Less Than 5 Days'
             WHEN big_exp > 5
                  AND big_exp < 20 THEN 'Between 5 and 20 Days'
             ELSE 'Greater than 20 days'
           END
    FROM   data
```